# How to create multi-layer view in android, with image and color?

Tags: android, view, textview, imageview, setbackground

I want to create a view with TextView at the foreground, and both image as well as color can be set at background.
Here are the images of view I am expecting.
[image] [image]
[image] [image]

I tried setting with setBackgroundView() method, but it either accepts image or color.
How can I achieve this effect?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you mean a background image and also some color front of it?

Comment: Yes. or color at the back and semi-transparent image over it.

Comment: @jagapathi I think he'll need an transparent image (png) in front of color and not vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

### Use FrameLayout

Replace Strings, Sizes and Drawable to match yours.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/purple_50">

    <ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/pattern"
    />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="@dimen/widget_margin"
        android:text="@string/content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_content"/>
</FrameLayout>
```